# s3a connector doesn't seem to commit at the end of spark job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop

I am using spark with s3a magic committer.

This is how I create my `SparkSession`:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("my app")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled", "true")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "magic")
    .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory")
    .config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol")
    .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "10")

    .config("spark.sql.orc.splits.include.file.footer", "true")
    .config("spark.sql.orc.cache.stripe.details.size", "10000")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning", "true")
    .getOrCreate()
```

I am using OBS from Huawei for object storage. It is compatible with s3a.

This is how I write my dataframe:

`df.write.orc("s3a://hdp-temp/orekhov-ps/remaining_clickstream_v3_partitions")`

From what I read in the docs about the magic committer, it is supposed to use s3's multipart upload API in order to upload data to object storage, but the data is not visible right then and there, it only becomes visible at the end of the job when a final POST request with etags is sent to the object storage.

In my case I am not seeing this sort of behavior. In my case I don't see all files appear at once, but I see them appear one by one as the job progresses. So, in my case, say, my spark job works for an hour, I will see a file in the first 5 minutes, then, in the next five minutes there will be another file, etc...

What is the problem here? Why does it act this way? Is this a problem with my object store or does s3a act the same on amazon's s3?

Here are some pictures of what I mean, in Spark UI I see 24 out of 199 completed tasks:

[image]

And in my object store I have 24 files:

[image]

Comment: you should expect to see .pending files appear under the __magic path as each file is written, a .pendingset file after each task commit. Files in the final dir should only appear in job commit. There's a hadoop command "hadoop s3guard uploads" to list in-progress uploads under a path to get that view of the job

Comment: @stevel I added pictures of what I see in Spark UI and in the file system. When I write into an empty directory I see both pendingset files in the __magic dir and output files in the final dir, as the job progresses I see more and more files in the final dir, they do not appear all at once at the end of the job. Do you have any idea what the issue could be? I am using proprietary Spark by Huawei. Maybe they messed something up in the s3a committers... Although I have no idea why they'd touch them at all. When I run vanilla Spark everything seems to work fine...

Comment: try a job against a real s3 store and see if it differs. if so: talk to your vendor. seems like in-flight files are manifest at the final destination (which is where we initiate the multipart uploads). seting org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a logs to DEBUG can help too. as for anything else, you are on own with a third party store, but filing a HADOOP JIRA might be interesting for all. include an ls -R listing though, not screen shots (hadoop fs -ls -R -h ) .

Comment: @stevel I did check the output files with "hadoop fs -ls" and they're there. I ran my job with vanilla spark and Huawei spark and vanilla spark works fine, there are no files in the output dir until the job commit. Whereas Huawei spark starts writing files right away.

Comment: @stevel maybe there's some setting in the multipart upload api or s3a that makes files visible right away when they've been uploaded without the need to do that final post request with etags?

Comment: This behavior seems like some kind of setting that can be turned on or off... Much like with the fileoutputcommitter algorithms.

Comment: oh, that's "not good". they are probably just faking multipart by creating a file with a posix api and then just appending each block as you go along. this works well for most use cases, but not here where we rely on it for commits. If the store does rename fast, try using the manifest committer (hadoop 3.3.5+), which is written for stores with atomic O(1) file rename but doesn't need atomic dir rename -targets GCS and ABFS, mainly

Comment: @stevel looks like the absence of this setting: `.config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol")` causes the files to be committed right away. Even on vanilla spark. The problem is that there's no Huawei version of `spark-hadoop-cloud` library, so I couldn't specify this. So I ended up copying the code of `BindingParquetOutputCommitter` and `PathOutputCommitProtocol` to my project and it seems to work fine.